# Database transfer between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-migration

I'm trying to help a client who's hosting company has decided to shutdown their hosting services and in that process I need to migrate an old ASP.Net site (DNN i think) to a new hosting company.

The old hosting company is running SQL Server 2000 and the new hosting company I'm attempting to copy it to has a 2008 version.

SQL Server Management Studio can connect to the old database ok but the Import/Export Data tool doesn't want to connect to this old system.

Is there anyway to easily transfer the database across?

Any tool you can recommend to backup a SQL 2000 db and restore it to a 2008 version or a migration tool that can converse between those two?

Comment: You really mean SQL Server **2000** (which is version 8.00) - right?

Comment: @marc_s You are correct indeed, sorry I wasn't aware the numbering worked like that (just went with reported version in Management Studio)

Comment: @marc_s Makes me feel slightly better

Comment: Microsoft marketing is .... shall we say .... innovative at times! :-) They come up with names and numbering schemes never seen before on this planet :-)

Comment: @marc_s  You would _think_ their own tool would report the correct product names...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just take a SQL Server database backup (using the built in backup features) from the SQL Server 2000 database, and restore it into SQL server 2008

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your input. How do I make the backup from Management Studio?

Comment: If you right click on the database in Object Explorer, choose Tasks and then Backup.

Comment: The old server throws a "Login failed for user userblabla_dbo" error when I right click on the database (but I can drill down and query the individual tables).. it's annoying, this is the dbo account..

Comment: You can generate the backup from the command line... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225964(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: chances are that you won't have enough permissions to do the backup or in fact pick it up afterwards.

Comment: So it appears the login problem only shows up on version 2012 of management studio. With 2008 version it works just fine (not sure why but good enough :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to you is

1. Get the host to shut down the SQL Server
2. Get the host to provide you with the files or the backups
3. Install your own SQL Server 2000 and then run the migration. Or just plain estore the backup in SQL2008

Comment: Dealing with the host is not an option, but I can connect to the server remotely. Can I do the backup myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to script database (schema + data): http://j.mp/NRb2EE and execute this script on new server. If database is large it can be huge script.

And remember to pay attention to the option Types of data to script – select option ‘Schema and data’.

Comment: Personally think that backup + restore is better option, but if you have problem with rights to do backup, you can try this.